# MySQL DB connection issues

Tags: mysql, airflow, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to mysql db using Airflow MySqlOperator operator. 
It is giving an error:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'hostname1'
```

The hostname i.e. hostname1 showing up in the error is totally different that the hostname (let's call it hostname2) that I entered in the Admin-> Connection console.

Also I executed the following command `SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER()` in mysql workbench using the username and hostname2 password in mysql workbench I get a 3rd different hostname for both `user()` and `current_user().`

If someone has any pointers as to how to fix/debug it, it would be great.

Comment: I'm assuming there could be a config that's setting the db values which is overriding your values? Maybe search for hostname1 in your project and see where that gets set!

Comment: Thanks Tim for taking a look. I am not using hostname1 anywhere in the project. I didn't even know something like that existed until I saw the error.

Comment: What do you get when you run airflow connections list? Do you see hostname1?